# C vector as char *** vector

Tags: c, vector

A function I need to use requires a vector argument for return storage with the following signature:

```
char ***vvar
```

What am I supposed to pass in there?
How do I access elements afterward?

Comment: To clarify: you has a function: f1(vector<?> w){ ...; return char*** vvar} ? or return vector<***char> ?

Comment: This question needs clarification. Does the function have any documentation? If not, could you try to clarify what you think it does: What does the vector contain? Strings? Is the memory for this vector supposed to be allocated by the function or yourself?

Comment: http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: @luke: Interesting discussion - thanks for the link!

Comment: I got my answer from the following answer... and my c-fu is doing better now!

Comment: to clarify.... the function is in a c lib API I need to access, has signature similar to -> int apyfunc(int from, int to, char ***returnRange)

Comment: I now do: char ** myVector; apyfunc( 1, 3, &myVector);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want a function that creates a vector of strings.  You might define it and call it like this:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

void make_vector(char*** vvar)
{
   /* We're going to create a vector of strings. */
   char** vector = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3 );
   vector[0] = "Hello";
   vector[1] = "world!";
   vector[2] = NULL;

   /* Now we give the address of our vector to the caller. */
   *vvar = vector;
}

int main(void)
{
   char** vector_of_strings = NULL;
   make_vector(&vector_of_strings);
   printf("%s\n", vector_of_strings[0]);
   return 0;  /* Memory leak is an exercise for the reader. :-) */
}
```

(In this example it would be simpler to have `make_vector` return the array, but in a more complex example it's reasonable to pass the address of `vector_of_strings`.)

Comment: Is it really necessary to cast malloc return value?

Comment: @Nyan: No, not in C, you're quite right.  Now fixed.  (I spend too much time mixing C and C++ :-)

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the vector will contain strings, as that makes the most sense with the signature you describe.
As you also did not give any code, I will assume the function you need to call looks similar to this:

```
/* This function creates a vector with room for 'length' strings and places it in 'vvar' */
void create_string_vector(int /* in */ length, char*** /* out */ vvar);
```

As the function expects to be able to change `vvar` and have that change reflected in the caller, you must pass the address of some variable, so the call should look like

```
create_string_vector(my_length, &my_var);
```

That takes care of one level of pointers.
This leaves just the question of how to declare `my_var`. As it will be a vector, or array, of unknown size, you need to declare it as a pointer. And a string is also a kind of array of unknown size of characters, so you need a pointer for that as well. This leads to the declaration

```
char* *my_var;
```

Element access is the easy part: You can treat `my_var` just as an array:

```
my_var[0] = "Hello";
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a vector by the looks of it.

If the function signature is somethings like function(...,char ***vvar,...), then your solution is not simple.

You need to know how much buffer space you need in each dimension, then create the complicated array as follows:

```
int dim_1 = 5, dim_2 = 4, dim_3 = 10;
char ***buffer = malloc(sizeof(char**)*dim_1);
for (int i=0;i++;i<dim_1) {
  char **buffer_2 = malloc(sizeof(char*)*dim_2);
  for (int j=0;j++;j<dim_2) {
    char *buffer_3 = malloc(dim_3);
    buffer_2[j] = buffer_3;
  }
  buffer[i] = buffer_2;
}
```

Comment: @Alexander Rafferty: And what **C** header do you include for the `new` operator?

Comment: I am very used to using the new operator, and if anyone would like to just change it to malloc that's fine. I don't understand why people are still using C (just my opinion).

Comment: @Alexander-Rafferty: because it's powerful and you can do bad things with it.

Comment: @Alexander: People still use C because either they have a lot of legacy code in C or because they work on a platform that does not have a C++ compiler,or just because they like C better.